# What is more efficient in AWS Lambda (Python), using /tmp/ or directly storing image in PIL.Image?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, python-imaging-library, tesseract

What is better performance wise? Here event["image"] holds base64 string.

## 1. Save to /tmp/image then read it back

```py
def main(event, context):
    image=base64.b64decode(event["image"])
    file1=open(r"/tmp/img","wb")
    file1.write(image)
    file1.close()
    txt = pytesseract.image_to_string("/tmp/img")
```

## 2. Directly store in PIL.Image

```py
def main(event, context):
    image = Image.open(BytesIO(base64.b64decode(event["image"])))
    txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(image)
```

I performed multiple tests in Lambda console and found first method to perform slightly better.

```
#1= ~2100ms
#2= ~2300ms
```

What explains better performance in first case? Can this distribution change under heavy load in production?

Comment: The first uses the JPEG/PNG decoder supplied with **tesseract**, the second uses the decoder supplied with **PIL/Pillow** - I would guess the difference lies therein, but you would need to test with JPEGs, PNGs of different sizes and type before coming to any conclusion.

Comment: Did you check how much time the base64 decoding is taking compared to the rest? ...it could be that the decoding is taking most of the time, and so the numbers look the same.
Did you also try playing with the memory assigned to the lambda?  That will change both memory _and_ CPU available - so tweaking that might also change your numbers.

Answer (score 0):

1st option is more preferable as if your image is required for each invocation of your Lambda. You may save it in tmp on startup and keep on using by reading it from /tmp.

Comment: Hey Rajesh - that won't work for what you describe.  ...Every time you invoke a lambda it's a fresh instance - meaning /tmp is empty.  Whatever you write into /tmp will disappear when your lambda finishes - it's not persistent between invocations.

Comment: @richard, Sorry for late reply. I faced same kind of issue but i was using java package. I had to design one pdf which required logo for each pdf generated by lambda. We put the image as resources in our jar. When Lambda was using this jar we could get it from /tmp. Lambda will not go in cold state immediately. For multiple iterations you can leverage it. Our volume was high so i decided to go with this approach. Hope it may help.